# Oracle 11g : ORA-04098: trigger 'SANCIONES_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've created a table in Oracle 11g whith an autoincrement field:

```
CREATE TABLE SOFOS.SANCIONES (
COD_SANCION NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
COD_USUARIO VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
FECHA_INICIO DATE NOT NULL,
FECHA_FIN DATE NOT NULL,
COD_GERENCIA NUMBER NOT NULL,
MOTIVO NUMBER NOT NULL,
COD_NOMBRE_CURSO VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
MOTIVO_LEVANTAMIENTO VARCHAR2(500)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE sanciones_seq;

DROP TRIGGER sanciones_trig;

CREATE TRIGGER sanciones_trig
BEFORE INSERT ON SANCIONES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT sanciones_seq.nextval
    INTO :NEW.COD_SANCION
    FROM dual;
END;
/
```

The thing is that I'm having an error like

> ORA-04098: trigger 'SANCIONES_TRIG' is invalid and failed
>   re-validation

...what am I doing wrong??

I have followed other examples but I still have the same error.

> Adding a semicolon after 'FROM dual;' solved the prblem as @krokodilko
>   sugested in the answers.

Comment: append a semicolon just after `.... FROM dual`. BTW you can use a simple assignment `:NEW.COD_SANCION := sanciones_seq.nextval;` instead of `SELECT ... FROM dual`

Comment: Thanks @krokodilko! that solved the problem

Comment: In some languages, statement terminators such as `;` are optional (or absent, as in SQL) but in PL/SQL they are mandatory. By the way, your edit corrects the syntax error so the question doesn't make sense any more.